# CMD file to backup external hard drive

Tags: windows-10, robocopy

I have an i7 processor on a laptop with speeds of approximately 2.8 GHz With 3.5 GHz turbo boost.

I want to create a `CMD` file to copy 20 directories From 1 external solid-state hard drive to a second external solid-state hard drive.

Additional requirements are:

1. Output a log with only the final summary from each of the major directories.
2. Save the output to a text file in `C:\data`. I want to only output the summary table for each directory copied with column headings total copied skipped mismatch failed extras and row headings dir files bytes and times?
3. While doing the copy pause between directory copies so all data will be copied and not be fragmented in memory.  I plan on running this at night.

I am not sure how to handle the pause nor the time for each pause?  For example, some of my copies take almost an hour even on solid-state external drives. Other directories are relatively short.

The code I'm currently running is `robocopy "e:\bundle" "f:\bundle" /E /256`

Help please! Thank you.

MM

Comment: Is there ever going to be more or less than 20 directories that you want to copy? Also, do you absolutely have to use a batch (`cmd`) file? If not, take a look at [Dropit](http://www.dropitproject.com/), it seems to be able to perform the tasks you require.

Comment: The number of directories will vary. I am trying to keep this under my control. My software library keeps expanding. I have created a . cmd file. Please see below.CD "F:\"
mkdir "AcademicSupport"
mkdir "bundle"
mkdir "mmstat"
robocopy "E:\AcademicSupport" "F:\Academic.Support"
robocopy "E:\bundle" "F:\bundle"
robocopy "E\mmstat"  "F:\mmstat"
timeout /t 30 /nobreak > NUL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you shouldn't need to add any kind of pause between each robocopy command, I've never had to in any of my personal or business use.

As far as getting logging and simplifying things, you can use the following:

```
F:
mkdir AcademicSupport bundle mmstat
call :script >"C:\Data\Backup-%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%.txt"

:script
robocopy "E:\AcademicSupport" "F:\AcademicSupport" /e /256 /tee
robocopy "E:\bundle" "F:\bundle" /e /256 /tee
robocopy "E\mmstat"  "F:\mmstat" /e /256 /tee
timeout /t 30 /nobreak > NUL
```

/tee on robocopy will output the results to the console window, which because of `call :script` will be logged to the global log file created by `call :script >`

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I have not tried your code yet but I wonder if that will output the summary table at the end with column headings total copied skipped mismatch failed extras and rows dir files bytes and times?

Comment: @MaryA.Marion Hi Mary, it will indeed output the robocopy summary for each individual robocopy command into the backup log file. If you want a combined summary of all three commands you'd have to use a PowerShell script or something of that nature as it isn't possible with robocopy

Comment: James, I have found a solution to output summaries only.
robocopy "E:\AcademicSupport" "F:\AcademicSupport" /E /256 /NC /NFL /NS /NDL /NP   What is left now is how to output the results to c:\data. It involves using the greater than sign > .

Comment: @MaryA.Marion That's why I have `call :script >...` in the code I provided, it is telling it to run the code below :script and write the output to `C:\Data` in a file named `Backup-YYYYMMYY-HHMMSS.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I am working out the details but the following line of code worked for me.
`robocopy "E:\AcademicSupport" "F:\AcademicSupport" /E /256 /NC /NFL /NS /NDL /NP`